# Knowing when GIF is done playing

Tags: java, animation, gif

I'm trying to display a GIF file to a JLabel. No problem I load the GIF and set it as the icon of the label. But now i really need to know when this ends, because it has to function as a cutscene. What i already tried is this (GameScene is a custom object but i know setIcon works, trust me) :

```
private GameScene scene;
private ImageIcon _temp;
private ImageIcon toplay;
private Thread anim;

public Cutscene(ImageIcon gif, GameScene scene, int length){
    this._temp = scene.getIcon();
    this.toplay = gif;
    this.scene = scene;
    anim = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            scene.setIcon(gif);
            scene.repaint();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(length);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
}

private void _s(){
    scene.setSolidColor(false);
    scene.setIcon(toplay);
    scene.repaint();
}

public void play(){
    _s();
    anim.start();
}

public void await(){
    try {
        anim.join();
        scene.setIcon(_temp);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now, Is there anyway I can achieve this without, just letting the whole program sleep for the given amount of time and then continue with the rest of the code and completely not drawing the GIF file?

Comment: Starting a question with "to get straight to the point" isn't.

Comment: You get the question right?

Answer (score 1):

This is a really simply example, it will only work with non-looping gifs, if your gif repeats you'll have to test the time between requests for `FRAMEBITS` and try and determine if you can detect the point at which loops.

```
public class MonitoringLabel extends JLabel {

    public MonitoringLabel(Icon image) {
        super(image);
    }

    public void addActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        listenerList.add(ActionListener.class, listener);
    }

    public void removeActionListener(ActionListener listener) {
        listenerList.remove(ActionListener.class, listener);
    }

    protected void fireActionPerformed() {
        ActionListener[] listeners = listenerList.getListeners(ActionListener.class);
        if (listeners.length > 0) {
            ActionEvent evt = new ActionEvent(this, 0, "stopped");
            for (ActionListener listener : listeners) {
                listener.actionPerformed(evt);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean imageUpdate(Image img, int infoflags, int x, int y, int w, int h) {
        boolean finished = super.imageUpdate(img, infoflags, x, y, w, h);
        if (!finished) {
            fireActionPerformed();
        }
        return finished;
    }

}
```

The above class provides an `ActionListener` which is triggered when the image "finishes" loading (this is triggered when their are no new frames in the animation to be played - repeating gifs never return `false`)

You can use a different listener interface if you want, I just threw it together as an example.

The reason I choose to override `imageUpdate` is because the `JLabel` is already acting as the `ImageObserver` to the image when it paints it, this way we can use the power of the `JLabel` without fussing about with manually painting a gif ... yes I've done it, it's pain

Comment: Looping gifs could be handled by incrementing a counter every time the `FRAMEBITS` flag is passed and only firing the action when the frame count is reached.

Comment: @teppic That would assume you know the number of frames, which isn't the easiest thing the obtain, you could "wait" for a given period of time a "hope" its "about" right two, but again, it assumes a certain amount of knowledge

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'll give this a try, but I'm currently not home.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thanks ! This works exactly how I wanted it to, thx man.

Comment: How, exactly, do I use this example? What do I have to do to get the signal of the GIF animation stopped? Please point me to an example, I'm totally clueless. Sorry, I just started coding in Java 5 days ago.

Comment: The basic concept is, you create an instance of `MonitoringLabel`, passing it the `Icon` of your GIF, you attach a `ActionListener` to it and that will notify  you when the GIF has stopped playing

Answer (score -1):

Would it be possible to make the GIF non-repeating with the program used to make it?  Most photo editors that make GIF images give you the option of making it repeating or not.

If I'm understanding your problem, it seems like you just want the gif to play once?

If it's for a cut scene, why not make the program sleep during that time?

Comment: That's exactly the problem as you can see in my code, it sleeps for a little while given by the user, but it just pauses the whole program for some reason. That's what i intended to do. But this is getting a little more helpfull :D

Comment: Well, sleep does pause the whole program at the point it's being called, for the set amount of milliseconds. I don't think I'm fully understanding the issue here.  If you need a all encompassing solution that figures out the length of the gif itself, I found imageObserver and imageReader classes in the Java docs that might help you. Specifically this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ImageObserver.html#FRAMEBITS

Comment: @JarnoGabriël That's because Swing is single threaded and using `Thread.sleep` will block the main thread, preventing it from updating the UI. You need to use a Swing `Timer` for that kind of operation

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know that about the main thread being blocked. :)