# Java - How can I pause code without pausing a GIF animation in my GUI?

Tags: java, user-interface, sleep

Currently I have a start menu for a game with a button which transform my menu background image from a PNG into a GIF after a button press. Now, I want my code to wait until the GIF animation is over. After that, it should continue normally (by opening a new JFrame with the actual game).

I've read some stuff about a swing timer, although I'm unsure of how to implement this as I am a Java beginner.

```
private ImageIcon a = new ImageIcon("a.png");
private ImageIcon b = new ImageIcon("b.gif");

class AddInterestListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        bgLabel.setIcon(b); //replace PNG with GIF

        //This here is where I want my delay to happen without freezing the GUI 

        JFrame game = new JFrame(); //Actual game frame starting etc.
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You may be able to use an ImageObserver. Once the image is complete the observer can open the frame.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Knowing when GIF is done playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077591/knowing-when-gif-is-done-playing)

Comment: Just a thought...I think you can start a thread that changes PNG to GIF. Then use something like thread.join(2000) to wait until that task is done.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use blocking methods like `Thread.sleep()` or `Thread.join()` in [Swing EDT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html). This will freeze the UI as Swing EDT handles all the UI refresh events.

You must implement this with events, first event blocks the UI second unblocks it. If you know the GIF animation length you can use [`SwingUtils.invokeLater()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) to run an async thread with that will fire the event after a fixed delay.

Comment: I've read about invokeLater because you mentioned it, but I can't get it to work. I think it's mostly due to the fact my English isn't that great and I'm an absolute beginner when it comes to any programming language really. How would I go about implementing events to pause my code? The example given on the oracle website is very confusing to me.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit] apparently there was already an answer and I don't know if that answer , or my answer for that matter, fits in your software. One thing I can say for sure is that my method allows you to use custom scaling algorithms etc instead of the built-in one (but you probably don't need that either).

---

Afaik it is not possible to monitor the progress of a GIF displayed using SWING. You'll have to make your own GIF decoder/animator in order for you to 'detect' when the GIF is about to loop or end (yes animated GIFs can end).

For that I used a 3rd party loader from https://github.com/DhyanB/Open-Imaging to obtain the individual frames and timing information. No guarantee that this is still the best library out there as I found this little over a year ago.

From there on you'll need to write your own animator using `javax.swing.Timer` or similar.